# How can I integrate this expression

Tags: integration

I looked over on the internet but I don't know hot to integrate this... Can someone give a hint

$$ \int \frac {\sqrt x} {x^2 -x + 1} dx $$

Comment: Use partial fractions and sub $x=u^2$, in which order is up to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

substituting $x=y^2$ we get

$$I=\int \frac{2y^2\:dy}{y^4-y^2+1}=2\int \frac{dy}{y^2+\frac{1}{y^2}-1}$$ so

$$I=\int \frac{1+\frac{1}{y^2}}{\left(y-\frac{1}{y}\right)^2+1}\;dy+\int \frac{1-\frac{1}{y^2}}{\left(y+\frac{1}{y}\right)^2-3}\;dy$$

so $$I=\int \frac{dz}{z^2+1}+\int \frac{dw}{w^2-3}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\dfrac{\sqrt x dx}{x^2-x+1} =\int\dfrac{2xd\sqrt x}{x^2-x+dx} = \int \dfrac{2u^2du}{u^4-u^2+1}, \text { where } u = \sqrt x.$$
HINT:
$$\dfrac{2u^2}{u^4-u^2+1} = \dfrac{2u^2}{u^4+u^2+1 -3u^2} = $$$$\dfrac{2u^2}{(u^2 -\sqrt 3u +1)(u^2 + \sqrt3 u +1)}$$$$=\dfrac {Au+B}{u^2 -\sqrt 3u +1} + \dfrac {Cu+D}{u^2 + \sqrt 3u +1}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Sunbsitution $x=y^2$ gives a rational expression and then partial fractions and be used.